# Multiplication sign, using '*' or 'x'

Tags: website-design, help

In mathematics, the operators provided on keyboard are quite clear for addition, subtraction and divide: `+ - /`.

The multiplication sign `*` might be familiar as the multiplication for programmer, but I'm not sure about ordinary user. I don't know if I should use `*` or `x` for multiplication.

The purpose is to provide user detail of how each field will be used:

[image]

One drawback I can think of is if using `x` might rely on font face and if user changes the font, `x` might not be appear like multiplication sign.

Also, by the standard `*` (asterisk) should be used to multiplication, but 
I'm not sure about its readability.

Comment: I always had the impression that "*" was used as a multiplication operator because "•", commonly used in algebra, was hard to find on older (particularly PC) keyboard layouts, but looked similar enough to be interchanged. I am not confident that * is a good multiplication operator for human consumption.

Comment: Please don't expect users to actually calculate the rates themselves! 
(Room Price + Charge) x Net Rate %, ...

Comment: @Wousser That is just a description of how each Apply Type will be used to calculate. The program will do it.

Comment: Why not use `×`?

Comment: @hippietrail at the time i was writing this question. i didn't know that sign existed :) Thanks

Comment: good reference for other codes https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It would certainly be a mistake to use the letter `x` as the multiplication symbol as `x` itself often denotes an algebraic term:

e.g. compare

x x y = c
`x x y = c`

vs

x × y = c
`x × y = c`

The `&times;` or `&#215;` or `&#D7;` character looks like this:  × so it is a proper cross, as opposed to the letter `x` (ex) or `*` (asterisk) symbols which are a lazy approach and don't create symmetrical symbols about the major axes.

The `&times;` version is simply the friendly version of the same code.

For additional reference, for *divide* you can also use `&divide;` or `&#247;` to get ÷

For *minus* you might expect to use direct from the normal key, but there is a separate code for that too `&#8722;` − which aligns it vertically with the keyboard plus symbol, so you get ( −+ `−+` ) instead of the keyboard minus and plus, which may not be aligned depending on the font ( -+ `-+` ).

You can get the plus/minus via `&plusmn;` or `&#177;` ± .

There is another Wikipedia [entry for the symbol itself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_sign), which currently consists of the information below:

(sorry, this is an image - so links are not real!)
[image]

Comment: Would be kind of nice if those were the symbols you got when using the keys on the numpad.

Comment: @Svish You mean pressing '/' would give you ÷ and pressing '*' would give you ×?

Comment: Looks to me like you're raising X to the X then multiplying by Y

Comment: There is a semantic difference for multiplication on non-scalars. For vectors `A × B` (cross product) is not the same as `A ∗ B` (dot product).

Comment: Ah, I never knew there was a Unicode for either the '×' OR '÷' symbol. (Well, TBH i've never really looked). Now I know.

Comment: also, don't forget to use `&lowast;` (∗) instead of an asterisk (*)

Comment: @root45 exactly. except the keys should have the correct print too of course.

Comment: and calculator software etc etc should react appropriately and such...

Comment: Roger, is there a better alternative to using the < and > keys on the keyboard?

Comment: got them. &lt; &LT; &#x0003C; &#60; for "less than". &gt; &GT; &#x0003E; &#62; for "greater than". https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

Answer (score 13):

It's a shame that I found the solution after posting my own question.
So I will just share it there. Wikipedia recommends using The HTML entity `&times;` which will be resulted in × for multiplication:

[Multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication)

[List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all of the other pro voices for *, the numeric keypad on my keyboard has a * for times.   That's another argument, IMO, for using it.

Comment: Absolutely not from a UI point of view. That is only an argument as to why it is easier, not as to why it is better.

Comment: +1 because, as my answer gets into, the asterisk is best used for consistency - from every perspective.  An `x` is only used in gradeschool math, and cross-products.

Answer (score 0):

Compare:

`x x y = c`  - Bad for obvious reasons

`x × y = c`  - Also bad, but less so.  It looks like `(x^x)*y` (x raised to the x, times y)

`x * y = c`  - I would consider this the obvious choice, especially since using dot for multiplication is standard for Pre-Algebra and beyond.  (Roughly age 13 or 14 and older in the US)

Comment: x × y = c is not bad, it is very much standard.